# MVC FromUri &amp%3B

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, datamodel

On the controller I have the following

```
Index([FromUri] SearchDataModel Search)
```

which is working fine. But now I am getting a URL like this  :

> https://mysite.com/?SearchName=Test&amp%3Bvalue1=value1&amp%3Bvalue2=value2&amp%3Bvalue3=value3

I need to support this URL but I can not get the parameters because of amp%3B
I tried to use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value);` in my model but it did not work ...

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

not same situation, but maybe helps... this is, how to accept hyphens in controller name...

**routing:**

```
var defaultRoute = routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{param}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", param = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

defaultRoute.RouteHandler = new HyphenRouteHandler();
```

**HyphenRouteHandler:**

```
public class HyphenRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        //here you can probably do your urlencoding

        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```